# btrfsck --repair out of memory

Tags: linux, btrfs

trying to repair a btrfs file system.

btrsfck --repair /dev/sda2

results in "out-of-memory" error

**top** seems to indicate that not more than 2gb-3gb was used.

It is a virtual machine, and so I added 30gb of RAM to it, and still "Out-of-memory".

[image]

dmesg

qgroup generation mismatch, marked as inconsistant.

Is there an alternate way of fixing this problem and/or how do I work around this one?

After disabling the quotas I get this the below.  However, the disk check still wants to run, and after 11 hours did not complete.

```
enabling repair mode
Checking filesystem on /dev/sda2
UUID: 8aaa7b6a-aaf0-4e83-acd1-2f289d178e41
checking extents
Fixed 0 roots.
checking free space cache
cache and super generation don't match, space cache will be invalidated
checking fs roots
root 271 inode 1134 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1135 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1136 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1137 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1138 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1141 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1142 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1144 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1145 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1149 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1150 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1151 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1152 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1153 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1154 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1155 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1156 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1157 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1158 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1159 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1160 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1161 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1162 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1163 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1164 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1165 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1166 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1168 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1169 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1170 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1171 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1172 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1173 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1175 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1176 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1177 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1178 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1179 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1180 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1181 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1182 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1183 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1184 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1185 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1186 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1187 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1188 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1189 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1190 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1191 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1192 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1193 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1194 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1195 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1196 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1197 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1198 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1199 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1200 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1202 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1203 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1204 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1207 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1208 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1209 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1210 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1211 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1212 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1213 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1214 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1215 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1216 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1217 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1218 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1219 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1220 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1221 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1222 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1225 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1226 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1227 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1228 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1229 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1230 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1231 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1232 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1233 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1234 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1235 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1236 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1237 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1238 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1239 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1240 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1241 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1242 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1245 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1246 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1247 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1248 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1249 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1252 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1253 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1254 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1255 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1256 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1257 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1258 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1259 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1260 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1261 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1263 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1266 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1267 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1269 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1270 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1272 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1273 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1274 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1276 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1277 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1279 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1282 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1283 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1285 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1288 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1289 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1291 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1292 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1293 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1294 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1296 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1297 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1298 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1299 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1300 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1301 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1302 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1303 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1304 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1306 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1307 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1308 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1309 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1310 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1313 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1314 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1316 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1318 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1319 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1322 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1323 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1325 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1326 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1328 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1329 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1331 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1334 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1335 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1338 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1339 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1340 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1341 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1342 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1343 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1344 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1345 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1347 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1348 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1350 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1353 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1355 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1356 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1357 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1360 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1361 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1363 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1365 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1366 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1367 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1370 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1371 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1373 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1374 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1376 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1378 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1379 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1380 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1382 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1383 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1384 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1385 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1386 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1387 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1389 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1390 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1391 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1393 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1394 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1395 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1399 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1400 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1402 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1403 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1405 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1407 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1408 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1409 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1410 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1411 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1413 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1414 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1415 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1416 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1417 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1418 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1419 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1420 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1421 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1422 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1423 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1424 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1425 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1427 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1428 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1430 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1431 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1432 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1433 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1434 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1436 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1437 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1438 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1439 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1440 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1442 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1443 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1444 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1445 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1446 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1447 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1448 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1449 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1450 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1452 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1453 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1455 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1457 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1459 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1460 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1461 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1462 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1463 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1464 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1465 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1466 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1468 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1469 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1470 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1471 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1472 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1474 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1475 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1476 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1477 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1478 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1479 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1481 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1483 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1484 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1485 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1487 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1489 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1491 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1493 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1495 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1496 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1499 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1504 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1507 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1510 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1513 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1516 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1520 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1523 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1524 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1529 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1530 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1533 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1536 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1537 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1539 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1540 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1543 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1545 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1546 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1548 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1549 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1550 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1552 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1554 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1556 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1557 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1558 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1559 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1561 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1564 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1566 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1569 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1576 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1577 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1578 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1585 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1591 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1594 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1595 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1596 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1599 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1601 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1602 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1605 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1608 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1615 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1618 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1644 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1648 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1656 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1659 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1749 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1750 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1751 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1755 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1758 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1759 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1762 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1765 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1766 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1767 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1769 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1771 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1773 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1776 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1778 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1780 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1782 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1787 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1788 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1792 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1793 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1794 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1795 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1798 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1801 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1804 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1807 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1808 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1809 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1810 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1813 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1815 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1816 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1817 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1819 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1822 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1825 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1828 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1831 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1834 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1837 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1840 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1843 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1846 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1849 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1852 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1855 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1858 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1861 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1864 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1867 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1868 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1870 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1873 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1876 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1879 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1882 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1885 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1888 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1891 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1894 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1897 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1900 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1903 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1906 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1909 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1912 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1913 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1915 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1916 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1917 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1918 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1920 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1923 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1926 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1927 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1929 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1932 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1935 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1936 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1938 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1941 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1944 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1947 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1950 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1953 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1955 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1957 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1958 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1960 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1963 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1964 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1966 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1969 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1970 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1972 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1973 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1975 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1976 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1978 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1979 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1980 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1983 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1985 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1987 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1989 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1990 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1991 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1993 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1994 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1996 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 1997 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 2000 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 2001 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 2002 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 2423 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 2425 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 3407 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 3611 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 3703 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 3888 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 3890 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 28118 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 28259 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 28263 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 28321 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 28322 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 28546 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 28551 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 32557 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 32558 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 32559 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 32560 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 34173 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 34174 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 34405 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 34406 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 34428 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 34429 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 34431 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 34432 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 34434 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 34435 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 34897 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 34898 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 35680 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 35684 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 35692 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 35696 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 35697 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 35699 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 35700 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 35701 errors 800, odd csum item
root 271 inode 35703 errors 800, odd csum item
checking csums
checking root refs
found 11789348864 bytes used err is 0
total csum bytes: 11111620
total tree bytes: 360939520
total fs tree bytes: 320929792
total extent tree bytes: 23527424
btree space waste bytes: 59768807
file data blocks allocated: 73642848256
 referenced 12917706752
```

Comment: How large is the drive, and is the VM 32- or 64-bit? [The `btrfs` wiki's "Gotchas" section](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gotchas#8TiB_limit_on_32-bit_systems) indicates that out-of-memory failures can occur if you have a large partition (>8TiB) and a 32-bit system.

Comment: @ErikF        It is 64 bit OS the drive is 20gb 30gb at the most I will have double check.

Comment: Focusing on the `qgroup generation mismatch, marked as inconsistant` error message, are you using actually quotas?  have you tried rescanning the qgroups with `btrfs quota recan <path>`?  or disabling quotas entirely with `btrfs quota disable <path>`?   BTW, see the "Stability Status" note in `man btrfs-quota`.  See also https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Quota_support.  btrfs quota support is not what I would consider to be reliable enough to use.

Comment: if you're not using quotas, then disable them.  quota support in btrfs is not production-ready, stable code.  it is known to have a performance impact.  That stability status note in the man page I mentioned says ***STABILITY STATUS
The qgroup implementation has turned out to be quite difficult as it affects the core of the filesystem operation. The users have hit various corner cases over time, eg. wrong accounting or system instability. The situation is gradually improving but currently (4.7) there are still issues found and fixed.***.

Comment: @cas Quotas may be enabled, but I am not using the functionality to limit anything.Had to boot from external media and the disable function says its not btrfs.  Yet it is, and btrfs check does not give said errors.

Comment: IMO the warning alone is reason enough not to enable quotas, or to disable them if already enabled.  The mention of "wrong accounting" sounds like it could be related to the problem you're having.

Comment: doesn't matter if you're actually using quotas or not - just enabling the feature is enough to cause performance and stability problems.  The same man page also say *PERFORMANCE IMPLICATIONS
When the quotas are turned on, they affect all extent processing, taking a performance hit. **It is not recommended to turn on qgroups unless the user intends to actually use them.***

Comment: @cas I mounted the volume and then I was able to disable them.  However, the system started a disk check again, which last time ran for 10 hours and never completed.(I rebooted)

Comment: After you recover & backup your data, or if you have a recent backup, I strongly recommend not using btrfs.  I had my own disasters with it years ago, and I've seen too many problems where people lose all the data they've entrusted to it, and every time I look at the docs, it says stuff like "this feature is experimental".  IMO you've got two basic choices. 1. if you want a modern COW filesystem with subvolumes and snapshots and compression and all the rest of it, switch to ZFS.  2. if that's not important to you, switch to using LVM (and/ormdadm too) and xfs.  or LVM/mdadm + ext4.

Comment: BTW does it pass a `btrfs-check` now that you've disabled quotas?

Comment: @cas Rebooted system waiting for a automatic disk check to complete, which I fear may run forever.  Even though all storage is SSD and **should** finish quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Something terrible happened

After doing a screen recording I noticed the boot volume had a different UUID for no good reason.

1. boot from live CD
2. edit search and replace /boot/grub2/grub.cfg

   old uuid -> new uuid

   System partially boots, but no kernel modules load....hmmm

After searching config files, I thought I would load the modules manually to see what the problem is.

Go to /lib/modules/4.15.8-1-default

!!SCREAM LOUDLY!!!

the subfolder **kernel** doesn't exist any more.

All the kernel modules were deleted!!!

Yikes!!!!

Back to a live DVD ISO

1. mount the drive.
2. active ssh service

Goto alternative computer

```
scp -rp /lib/modules/4.15.8-1-default/* root@1.1.1.1:/lib/modules/4.15.8-1-default
```

Reboot

The system boots normall????

Time to build a new VM a migrated the important files over.